# Python using a input in a function outside of the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code bellow keeps outputting an error as variable "user_option" (which is holding an input value) is not available outside of the function. How do i make it available so i can use it for my if statement?

```
def main_menu(str):
    print(str(1) + " Play game")
    print(str(2) + " High score")
    print(str(3) + " Joke")
    user_option = input("What option would you like to select? ")
    return(user_option)

main_menu(str)

if user_option == "1" or user_option == "Play game" or user_option == "play game":
```

The reason I want it as a function is I have an option for the user to return to main menu screen and input a new option.

Comment: `user_option = main_menu(str)`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you are passing in `str` it is built-in

Comment: `str(1) + " Play game"` == `"1 Play game"`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to collect the `return` value.

```
user_option = main_menu(str)
```

However, you may want to rename `str` as that is a built-in keyword in Python.

Answer (score -4):

If that is the only instance of that variable you can cast it as global

```
global user_option = input("What option would you like to select? ")
```

Comment: There is no need for global variables here. Check out [why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: Not only is there no need for a global variable here, what is written is a syntax error. And "casting" to global doesn't make sense.